# Can I use 'oversight' in this context?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context, sentence-usage

This is an excerpt from a journal entry I am writing for my first-year university transition course:

> The annual pep rally is mandatory for all students, despite taking place in a crowded, hot gymnasium and making extensive use of strobe lights and deafening acoustics. This mandate exposes an atrocious **oversight** of students suffering from a variety of common mental health issues.

Can I use *oversight* in this context? I cannot find any other examples of 'an oversight of' on the Internet, unless the term is used to mean *overseeing*.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: No, I don't think you can. Do you mean _a disregard for the needs of students [with] mental health issues_?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, that is what I mean.